# Deleting Rows from CSV file using DictWriter

Tags: python, csv

[image]Here is a very basic sample of what I'm looking to do
I want to delete a row (or set of rows, using a list) with the DictWriter library but I don't know the syntax for row deletion
This is what I have so far

```
import csv

filename = "sampletable.csv"
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile: 
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    
    with open("samplerowdeletion.csv", "w") as newfile:
        fieldnames = ["high","low","precipitation"]
        csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(newfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csvwriter.writeheader() 
        
        for row in csvreader:
            del(row[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading from one csv and writing some of the rows to another csv is an example of [filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(higher-order_function)).  The easiest way to do this is by skipping the rows that you don't want:

```
for row in reader:
    if row['high'] == '10':
        # go back to the top of the loop
        continue
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Instead of hardcoding the check, you could write a function that will return `True` if a row should be kept and `False` otherwise (this kind of function is known as a *predicate*):

```
def is_ok(row):
    if row['high'] in list_of_bad_values:
        return False
    return True

for row in reader:
    if not is_ok(row):
        # go back to the top of the loop
        continue
    writer.writerow(row)
```

You avoid the explicit `for` loop by using Python's [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) built-in function, or a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def is_ok(row):
    # Shorter version
    return not (row['high'] in list_of_bad_values)
 
# Using filter
good_rows = filter(is_ok, reader)
writer.writerows(list(good_rows))

# Using a list comprehension
good_rows = [row for row in reader if is_ok(row)]
writer.writerows(rows)
```

If you want to filter by row number, you can use the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function.  `enumerate` will generate a row number for each row, starting at zero - you can adjust this by passing a `start` argument:

```
enumerate(some_iterable, start=1)
```

```
import csv

ROWS_TO_DELETE = [3, 4]

def is_not_ok(row_number):
    return row_number in ROWS_TO_DELETE
    

filename = "sampletable.csv"
with open(filename, 'r', newline=") as csvfile: 
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    
    with open("samplerowdeletion.csv", "w", newline=") as newfile:
        fieldnames = ["high","low","precipitation"]
        csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(newfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csvwriter.writeheader() 
        
        for row_number, row in enumerate(csvreader):
            if is_not_ok(row_number):
                continue
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Alternatively, you could make a row counter variable and manually increment it

```
filename = "sampletable.csv"
with open(filename, 'r', newline=") as csvfile: 
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    
    with open("samplerowdeletion.csv", "w", newline=") as newfile:
        fieldnames = ["high","low","precipitation"]
        csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(newfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csvwriter.writeheader() 
        
        row_number = 0
        for row in csvreader:
            if row_number in ROWS_TO_DELETE:
                continue
            writer.writerow(row)
            row_number += 1
```

Comment: The first solution seems the most beneficial to my situation, however it did not remove the row in the writer file. It added a new row inbetween each of the existing rows

Comment: Ah - in the question you are using two different files, but you actually want to reuse the original?

Comment: I want the reader file to be read, delete select rows and then the writer to produce a new file with the same data as the reader, just without the rows i chose to delete

Comment: (1) add `newline=''` to both of the `open` statements - `with open(filename, ..., newline='')`  (2) can you edit the question to add a few sample rows, and the criteria for selecting which are to be removed?

Comment: I dont have a specific criteria, as this is only a very basic sample that i am trying to get the hang of. i just want to delete specific rows e.g. row 1 or row 2

Comment: I've added a couple of examples of filtering by row number.

Comment: In the last example ROWS_TO_DELETE isnt defined

Comment: You can use the same declaration as in the previous example.