# Code to Extract Data Based on Criteria in CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a comma delimited text file containing 2M+ records with multiple columns. I would like a way to extract only the columns and rows I need based on values in other columns.

Criteria:  
ODBIC = YES 
NAM = 1 OR 2

Keep columns:
 ACC | NUM | NAM | ODBIC (and remove all the rest)

Sample data below:

```
INDEX,ACC,NUM,SUBSCRIBED,PN,PDP,NAM,ODBIC
1,37412900,1221222121,0,-1,-1,1,YES
1,37412911,2323232323,0,-1,-1,2,YES
1,374123434,3434343434,0,-1,-1,343,1
1,374129232,-1,0,-1,-1,434,YES
```

End result:

| ACC | NUM | NAM | ODBIC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 37412900 | 1221222121 | 1 | YES |
| 37412911 | 2323232323 | 2 | YES |

As it's 2M+ records doing in Excel is tedious and time consuming. I came across recommendations to do in Python but not sure how to write the code.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65049637/5320906) answer of mine might be helpful.

Comment: Do you how to use python?

Comment: Also consider using Pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/). It's a great tool for these types of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `pandas` module

```
pip install pandas
```

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = "path_to_csv_file"
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)

data = data[(data["ODBIC"] == "YES") & ((data["NAM"] == 1) | (data["NAM"] == 2))]
data = data[["ACC", "NUM", "NAM", "ODBIC"]]

data.to_csv("result.csv")
print(data)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
        ACC         NUM  NAM ODBIC
0  37412900  1221222121    1   YES
1  37412911  2323232323    2   YES
```

The results will be saved to `result.csv` file

Answer (score 1):

Just adding here for completeness - there is another option to use `.query()` which is sometimes more readable:

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = "path_to_csv_file"
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)

data = data.query('ODBIC == "YES" and (NAM == 1 or NAM == 2)')
data = data[["ACC", "NUM", "NAM", "ODBIC"]]

data.to_csv("result.csv")
print(data)
```